# Heating not turning on

Tags: heating

I live in a warm place, so I never use the heating. It is only a few weeks in the year that it gets cold enough for me to turn the heating, so this is the first time I tried to turn on the heating. However, I set the thermostat to the highest setting and there is no heat:
[image]
I checked the heating unit and everything looked fine:
[image]
[image]
I also reset the breakers to make sure this wasn't the issue
[image]
and doubled checked the thermostat to ensure that was installed correctly
[image]
I can't figure out what's wrong with my unit. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Two initial thoughts... First, look for a switch on or near the furnace. It'll look like a light switch. Then, the unit won't run with the bottom panel open. Close that up before you try again. Any sounds from the furnace when you power it up?

Comment: Is this a heat pump?

Comment: I see a spare fuse in there it could be a sign it blows fuses

Comment: I've had issues like this with my, rather old, furnace. Each time the control board had been fried by a slight bit of flooding my my root-cellar basement. Has your furnace been wet at all since the last time you used it?

Comment: The thermal cut-off switch could also be bad, though less likely with its limited use.  That is easy to test,  I usually bypass it with a screwdriver and see if it starts properly.

Comment: @raft at 240v 50+ amps that is the worst advice I have seen here. This is not a good candidate for bypassing unless learning arc welding with a side of flash burns.

Comment: Turn the fan from auto to manual.   If it comes on, you  know you are getting power to the system and can stop fooling with circuit breakers.

Comment: @SteveWellens the fan turns on when manual, as far as I know the furnace has never been wet (it's relatively new, 1 year old)

Comment: Do you use cooling? The filter may be plugged and an air flow switch is not allowing the heat relay to pull in as another possibility pull the filter and see if it starts heating , not good to run without a filter but another possibility

Comment: Please also check the setting in the thermostat to see at what temperature the heat is supposed to come on. It may need adjusting. Saw this in a house in Florida where heat onset temperature was too high or was at default setting. Heating needs in warm climes may be ignored or not set properly.

Answer (score 1):

I see a spare fuse in there it could be a sign it blows fuses

also check at the heat elements there is a mechanical thermal safety for over temp. Most electrics have a breaker panel on the unit itself.
I can not tell the breaker values feeding the unit if there are multiple breakers it is is back to the controls again back to the fuse or thermal limit.
I only see 1 element with the yellow blue wires the blue wire is connected to the thermal limit tap that black thing and yes there could be power right there.

So a control fuse is open or the limit, if the thermostat is sending the call for heat those art the 2 prime suspects.

If you have a volt meter and know how to use we may offer more help

Comment: where do you see the spare fuse? I don't see a breaker panel on my unit itself. What are the heat elements exactly? I have a rudimentary knowledge on how to use a multimeter, what should I do?

Comment: The fuse is just below the heating element on the shelf with some black tape holding it in place (standard tubular glass fuse with silver caps). Measure to see if there is voltage at blue wire to yellow wire if there is 240 there the limit is bad (black thing on blue wire I think it is 140 f but can’t really tell it gets two fuzzy. The heat element(s) are usually pull out cartridges or units yours could be 7.5 or 10kw not sure. The elements are almost always made of NiChrome wire a special wire used to create high heat when enough power the wire glows red hot and we use these for electric heat

Comment: I saw that fuse too above the fan on the shelf (2nd picture). Maybe someone pulled it out and forgot to put it back.